# How to transform my dataframe in specific way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with all binary values in each column:

```
col1    col2   col3  
1         0      1
1         0      1
1         1      1
0         0      0
1         0      0
```

I want to turn each row into set with column name as key and value as value. So desired result must look like this:

```
[{'col1:1', 'col2:0', 'col3:1'},
{'col1:1', 'col2:0', 'col3:1'},
{'col1:1', 'col2:1', 'col3:1'},
{'col1:0', 'col2:0', 'col3:0'},
{'col1:1', 'col2:0', 'col3:0'}]
```

How could i do that?

Comment: `df.to_dict('records')` ?

Comment: @DaniMesejo no, it will give [{'col1':1, 'col2':0, 'col3':1},.....

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: i need [{'col1:1', 'col2:0', 'col3:1'},.... value is in apostrophe

Comment: @ALollz yeah right. i edited question, its set

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Also, just to confirm, your desired output is a list of sets which contain strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
res = [{f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in d.items()} for d in df.to_dict('records')]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'col1:1', 'col3:1', 'col2:0'}, {'col1:1', 'col3:1', 'col2:0'}, {'col1:1', 'col3:1', 'col2:1'}, {'col2:0', 'col1:0', 'col3:0'}, {'col1:1', 'col2:0', 'col3:0'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with pandas you can `radd` the strings then apply set. (Probably overkill and slow due to the apply)

```
df.astype(str).radd(':').radd(df.columns).apply(set, axis=1).tolist()
[{'col1:1', 'col2:0', 'col3:1'},
 {'col1:1', 'col2:0', 'col3:1'},
 {'col1:1', 'col2:1', 'col3:1'},
 {'col1:0', 'col2:0', 'col3:0'},
 {'col1:1', 'col2:0', 'col3:0'}]
```